# Perforce branching

Tags: c#, perforce

I need to make some test changes on app. The app has version control (by Perforce). How to make a branch (from Perforce) that I don't intend on check back in so that I can do some test modification.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you mean by not intending to check it back in. Do you mean never, or just not into the main branch?

If you really just want to make some local changes, and then throw them away, without needed any form of version control on the changes themselves, then you don't need to branch at all. Just sync up, check out what you're changing, and then revert the files afterwards. You can even re-sync the files while you're working (resolving conflicts) if you want to check your local changes in the later build. Just don't submit anything, and you're good (just remember that P4 has no backup of your local changes, so if your PC dies and you didn't back it up, tough).

If you want to be able to switch between your local changes and your normal build, you could 'shelve' your changes, which essentially submits them into P4, but keeps them in a changelist rather than having them actually integrated into the main branch. That way you can revert back to the "real" version of the files, and re-sync your own changes again later - possibly even on a different machine. This is a lightweight way of being able to make local changes, while still having a copy on the P4 server without polluting the depot.

If however you want a proper change-tracked branch of your own, you could integrate the version you want to base it on over into a fresh part of the depot, and then use a client-spec which syncs with that while working on it. You are free to integrate between your branches in either direction, whenever you want. You can branch either the whole tree, or just a sub-set of it, using client-specs to sort out which bits go where.

Alternatively the recent versions of P4 have "streams", which are an alterative way of handling your depot, more suited to running multiple development and release branches in parallel. It's probably not what you're looking for.

In terms of exactly *how* to do these things, I recommend checking out P4's website, which has pretty good documentation and lots of tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you do not need to create new branch for test your change. Just make a client containing your app and sync your local computer. After that you need to change on specific files or add new or delete by shelve. Then just build your app with shelve. If you find your change at build artifact and if you think that your change is correct then you can submit it to perforce.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing is to go to the "steams" tab.  Create a new stream and check the check box for branch from where you want to branch from.  Super easy.